# Problem while importing 'jsonwebtoken' in vite-react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, vite

Whenever I am importing **jsonwebtoken** in my **vite-react** project. I am getting the following error in my browser console:
[Screenshot of error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3toq.png)

I tried to fix this problem by installing **@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill** and configuring the **vite.config.js** but it didn't work.

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
    import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [react()],
        optimizeDeps: {
            esbuildOptions: {
                // Node.js global to browser globalThis
                define: {
                    global: 'globalThis'
                },
                // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
                plugins: [
                    NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                        buffer: true
                    })
                ]
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this way:

```
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).